# connection failed in apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and installed raspbian-buster on it.

`sudo apt-get update` works well. But `sudo apt-get upgrade` shows connection failed.

> Err:29 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf arandr all 0.1.9-2+rpt4
>
> Connection failed [IP: 93.93.128.230 80]
>
> Err:1 http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf cron armhf 3.0pl1-134
>
> Connection failed [IP: 169.229.226.30 80]
>
> Err:30 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf libraspberrypi-doc armhf 1.20190620+1-1
>
> Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.39 80]
>
> Err:2 http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libk5crpyto3 armhf 1.17-3
>
> Connection failed [IP: 169.229.226.30 80]
>
> Err:31 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf libraspberrypi-dev armhf 1.20190620+1-1
>
> Connection failed [IP: 93.93.130.104 80]
>
> ..........

When I pinged to that IP addresses, there was no packet loss.

I tried `sudo apt-get clean`, but the same problem still occurs.

Comment: When you say the problem is not solved, do you mean that you still get a failed connection, or that you now have a connection, but the apt system isn't able to recover?

Comment: @BenCrowell Still same problem(connection failed). edited

Comment: Unfortunately this is not uncommon just after the Foundation does a major release. Keep trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Milliways said,  it seems because of the problem in the major release.

After I downgrade to Stretch, the 'connection failed' problem does not occur.

Comment: Please accept your answer with click on the tick on the left side. It finishes the question and will not pop up again months for months.